# How to count elements in group in stimulsoft report

Tags: c#

I have some problem with function Count(). I want to make this report

[image: Table example]

In first column use function Count() in second some group of element.
How I can create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("abc");
list.Add("foo");
list.Add("bar");
```

first column:

```
list.Count();
```

second column:

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
   // show item
}
```